Unable to print Chinese characters in VSCODE using python
I am experiencing a problem when trying to print chinese characters in VSCODE using python. the characters are not coming correctly. Please see the output. Please help.

My encoding is selected as UTF-8 already.  Python version : 3.12 VS
code version : 1.92.1 OS : Windows NTX64 10.0.19045

data = "中國哲學書電子化計劃"
print(data)

Output : ������Ǯѹq�l�ƭp��



What's about your terminal(system) encoding?

This mean your .py file in utf encoding.
Try terminal command
chcp 65001

Also check this: How can I use Unicode characters on the Windows command line?

You can activate UTF-8 for worldwide language support in Control Panel-Languages and Region: 
Inbasu's answer chcp 65001 would do the trick aswell.
